# jar file to exe losts pictures

Tags: java, image, jar, exe, launch4j

I made the following code to put in pictures to my java program:

```
private String ICET = "." + File.seperator + "Bilder/ICET.jpg"
//some code
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ICET));
//some code
```

It does, that the label has an IconImage and it works in every Workspace with a folder "Bilder", which is situated in the same folder as the program.
It works as a jar-file too, but if I convert the jar-file to an exe using launch4j, the program does not show the pictures.

Comment: You need to load images from the classpath, not a relative path

Answer (score 0):

use

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("path"));
```

path -> if is same folder put only name image : "ICET.jpg"

Comment: I solved it in another way: 'label.setIcon (new ImageIcon (Bilder\\ICET.jpg)' It works as a exe file too if the dirictionary stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the working directory set when started as an exe differs from when it is started as a jar-file, and thus your program looks at the wrong place for your "Bilder" folder.

You could try this out by printing the absolute path for it, e.g. like this:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

To fix the issue, you might try to set the `chdir`-option in the launch4j-config to `.` (a single dot). According to [the docs](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html):

> <chdir>
>
> Optional. Change current directory to an arbitrary path
>   relative to the executable. If you omit this property or leave it
>   blank it will have no effect. Setting it to . will change the current
>   dir to the same directory as the executable. .. will change it to the
>   parent directory, and so on.

But in the end, you should load the images from the class path, and not just from a folder. If you read them from the class path, they should hopefully be integrated into the exe, otherwise they are not and might get missing when users copy to exe to a new location, making your program no longer functioning.